# AWS Athena asynchronous pagination in Python

Tags: pagination, amazon-athena

I am creating an Athena connector for my Python application but large results take too long to process if I go with the usual synchronous pagination. Thus, I was curious if there is provision for asynchronous pagination through the Boto client or some other solution for optimized execution of large query results.

Answer (score 0):

I found it to be much more performant to retrieve the query results file from the S3 results bucket and then (for my use case) transform the CSV into a Pandas dataframe than to use the boto3 paginator.

```
from boto3.session import Session
import pandas #you will have to pip install s3fs

ACCESS_KEY='your access key'
SECRET_KEY='your secret key'

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

s3 = session.resource('s3')

bucket = 'your results bucket'
key = queryExecutionId + '.csv' #the query execution id from the response

obj = s3.Object(bucket, key) 

obj = obj.get()

frame = pandas.read_csv(obj['Body'])
```